# Removing HTML tags and converting to string using JSON?

Tags: python, html, json, unicode, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have the below code, which returns data from the Guardian API:

```
import requests
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags

def get_content():
    api_url = 'http://beta.content.guardianapis.com/football'
    payload = {
        'api-key':              '',
        'page-size':            10,
        'show-editors-picks':   'true',
        'show-elements':        'image',
        'show-fields':          'all'

    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, params=payload)
    data = response.json() # convert json to python-readable format
    data2 = "".join(data)
    print remove_tags(data2).encode('utf-8')
    return data
get_content()
```

How do I remove all the HTML tags returned in the result and convert to Unicode? I have done something similar before using XML within scrapy, where the following pieces of logic have worked:

```
print remove_tags(body2).encode('utf-8')
```

In this examplem 'body2' is a string.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post what an example of `data2` looks like before you try to remove the tags and convert to unicode?

Comment: @cyber thanks for replying. my screen print looks like this: 'ers acted quickly to seal the deal for a player who scored 39 goals for Barcelona in his three seasons at the club after joining from Udinese.</p><p>\u201cI\u2019m so happy to be joining Arsenal, a club which has a great manager, a fantastic squad of players, huge support around the world and a great stadium in London,\u201d said S\xe1nchez.</p><p>\u201cI\u2019m looking forward to meeting my new team-mates and to be playing for Arsenal in the Premier League and Champions League. I will give my best to Arsenal and want to make a...'

Comment: Have you tried adding the format=json parameter to the API call to get the data back in a more computer-readable form?

Comment: @Ben no i havent. what would be the exact syntax for that? thanks

Comment: Add it to your payload dict... 'format': 'json'

Comment: @Ben that hasnt made any change to the output unfortunately...

Comment: Use an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup4 or `lxml.html` to parse the HTML and strip the tags/extract the text.